# Why is the natural logarithm represented by $\ln$?

Tags: mathematics, notation

The natural logarithm is often represented by several different notations:

- $\log_e x$
- $\log x$ (although this is also used for logarithms with a base of 10)
- $\ln x$

It is the third notation that has me wondering. Why is $\ln$ used, and not, say, $\text{nl}$? My two theories about this are

1. It is an abbreviation for "natural logarithm" in a non-English language
2. It is meant to correspond with the "$l$" in typical logarithmic notation.

Why is the notation $\ln$?

Comment: I guess this just stands for Logarithm Natural (in some languages like French, they use this order of the words). Do you really think that this is really an interesting/important question on the history of Math and Sciences?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko It's about the history of notation, which is a valid subject.

Comment: In pure mathematics (unlike in applied computations) they use only natural logarithm. So they abbreviate it as $\log$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yep, I read that; $\ln$ is used mainly in physics and engineering.

Comment: Formally this is a valid subject. But on my opinion the question is trivial and not important.

Comment: In Spain and Spanish-speaking countries, ln = 'logaritmo natural', but more frequently 'logaritmo neperiano'

Answer (score 8):

As far as I am aware, the mathematical operator commonly spelled $\ln$ is an abbreviation of the Latin term,  [***l**ogarithmus **n**ātūrālis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/natural_logarithm).

I am not sure who first used this abbreviation, but I suppose it very well may have been Napier.

I remember having seen *ln* written as an abbreviation of two words in the form $l.n.$

Comment: This question (of course) has been asked before. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-did-the-notation-ln-for-log-base-e-become-so-pervasive, and note the answer by Velleman, which gives support to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Earliest Uses of Function Symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/functions.html) :

> $\ln$ (for natural logarithm) was used in 1893 by Irving Stringham (1847-1909) in [Uniplanar Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=BTY7AQAAIAAJ) ([Cajori](https://books.google.it/books?id=bT5suOONXlgC&pg=PA107) vol. 2, page 107).

Thnaks to KCd's reference in his comment, we have an earlier occurrence :

- Anton Steinhauser, [Lehrbuch der Mathematik für höhere Gewerbeschulen](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=ZzU7AQAAIAAJ&dq=Anton+Steinhauser+Lehrbuch+der+Mathematik&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=ln) (1875), page 277.

Comment: I should have seen that! I was looking in a related page the other day. Any idea why Stringham chose it?